# how to select map columns in hive query

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, datastax

I am using DSE4.5 and i have created dynamic column family by map collection.
Is there any way by that i can select map columns from cassandra table and run aggregation on it by using hive query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following built-in collection functions are supported in hive:

[image: list of built-in collection functions]

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF